# How do I log queries in a rake task using datamapper and padrino?

Tags: ruby, rake, datamapper, padrino

I have a padrino install that is using datamapper and logging queries to a file. This is working fine when browsing my application. But queries are not logged if executed inside a rake file. Why?

This is how the task is defined:

```
# lib/tasks/example.rake
task :example => :environment do
  players = Player.all #Player is a datamapper object
  puts players.first.to_s
end
```

I also added this line to /config/boot.rb

```
Padrino::Logger::Config[:development] = { :log_level => :devel, :stream => :to_file }
```

And this line is called in /config/database.rb

```
DataMapper.logger = logger
```

And this is how I'm executing the script

```
$ padrino rake example
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke rake with:

```
PADRINO_LOG_LEVEL=development padrino rake my:task
```

Comment: That works, but is DataMapper.finalize called after the task? or should I add it to the rake file?

Comment: padrino rake call `config/boot` so will be invoked before task.

Comment: Thanks. I added this line PADRINO_LOG_LEVEL= PADRINO_ENV to config/boot . Shouldn't it be in there by default??

Comment: Can be great when like you we use `:to_file` but with `:stdout` can be tricky see a decent output. Btw feel free to open an issue on github tracker.